# terraform rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service proto.Provider

Tags: terraform

I've been working on my own provider for terraform using our own infrastructure that we have implemented. It works fine using the binary from github but when I tried to merge template provider into the .tf file it complained that client version was ahead of the api server.

I resolved this first problem downloading the Alpha2 build and using both the binary and template provider provided in the zip file.

Now I am running into this error and I have no clue where to look.

```
rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service proto.Provider
```

The trace output of terraform apply

```
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.12.0 alpha2 
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.11.1
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/home/trent/go/bin/terraform", "apply"}
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /home/trent/.terraformrc
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"apply"}
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] command: no config, returning nil
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] command: no data state file found for backend config
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "fef78a22-83aa-6f9e-1e26-45747e4ca26b"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] command: backend initialized: <nil>
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/home/trent/go/bin"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [WARN] found legacy provider "terraform-provider-template"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/linux_amd64"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [WARN] found legacy provider "terraform-provider-test2"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "template", "0.0.0", "/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "test2", "0.0.0", "/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/home/trent/go/bin"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/linux_amd64"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] command: backend <nil> is not enhanced, wrapping in local
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [INFO] backend/local: starting Apply operation
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state manager for workspace "default"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] backend/local: reading remote state for workspace "default"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] backend/local: retrieving the local state snapshot for workspace "default"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] backend/local: building context for current working directory
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: starting
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: resolving provider version selections
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: loading provider schemas
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "template"
2018-11-29T07:48:59.264+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path=/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template args=[/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template]
2018-11-29T07:48:59.264+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin started: path=/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template pid=20045
2018-11-29T07:48:59.264+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for RPC address: path=/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template
2018-11-29T07:48:59.268+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: using plugin: version=5
2018-11-29T07:48:59.268+1000 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-template: plugin address: address=/tmp/plugin059266420 network=unix timestamp=2018-11-29T07:48:59.268+1000
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: GetSchema
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: PlanResourceChange
2018-11-29T07:48:59.520+1000 [WARN]  plugin: plugin failed to exit gracefully
2018-11-29T07:48:59.521+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/home/trent/go/bin/terraform-provider-template pid=20045 error="signal: killed"
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "test2"
2018-11-29T07:48:59.522+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path=/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2 args=[/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2]
2018-11-29T07:48:59.522+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin started: path=/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2 pid=20056
2018-11-29T07:48:59.522+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for RPC address: path=/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2
2018-11-29T07:48:59.541+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: using plugin: version=5
2018-11-29T07:48:59.541+1000 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-test2: plugin address: address=/tmp/plugin108198902 network=unix timestamp=2018-11-29T07:48:59.541+1000
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: GetSchema
2018/11/29 07:48:59 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: PlanResourceChange
2018-11-29T07:48:59.794+1000 [WARN]  plugin: plugin failed to exit gracefully
2018-11-29T07:48:59.795+1000 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/home/trent/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-test2 pid=20056 error="signal: killed"

Error: Failed to retrieve schema from provider "test2": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service proto.Provider
```

To me, it seems like I have to initialize something else for my provider for it to run properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it by checking out the alpha 2 branch on github. A more indepth response is provided here.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19501

Answer (score 0):

A dump restart of my laptop solved the problem for me.  I tried a dozen other solutions before, none worked.  I think it was a OS level issue.